# Sitecore: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Sitecore.Data.ID.operator !=(Sitecore.Data.ID, Sitecore.Data.ID)'

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

For the following code: I am getting an error mentioned in subject.

```cs
var subsidiariesIdList = new List<ID>();

MultilistField multilistField = newsItem.Fields["Recipient Subsidiaries"];
foreach (var item in multilistField)
{
    var data = Sitecore.Data.ID.Parse(item.ToString());

    if (data != null) // I am getting error here 
        subsidiariesIdList.Add(data);
}
```

Here is the complete error text:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Sitecore.Data.ID.operator !=(Sitecore.Data.ID, Sitecore.Data.ID)' and 'Sitecore.Data.ID.operator !=(Sitecore.Data.ID, Sitecore.Data.ShortID)'

Answer (score 5):

Just cast null to `ID`:

```cs
if (data != (ID)null)
```

The reason why you need to cast is that `ID` class has 2 operators defined:

```cs
public static bool operator ==(ID id1, ID id2)
public static bool operator ==(ID id1, ShortID id2)
```

The have different implementation and null can be both `ID` or `ShortID`. You need to tell compiler which one to use.

Comment: Thanks, it would be great to know a little why should I put `(ID)` with `null`

Comment: I've added explanation to my answer.

Comment: Or you can null check with Sitecore.Data.ID.IsNullOrEmpty(data), which does not rely on you knowing what type to expect 'data' as

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `IsNullOrEmpty` extension method on the `ID` type:

```
var subsidiariesIdList = new List<ID>();

MultilistField multilistField = newsItem.Fields["Recipient Subsidiaries"];
foreach (var item in multilistField)
{
    var data = Sitecore.Data.ID.Parse(item.ToString());

    if (!ID.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
        subsidiariesIdList.Add(data);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Does the code you supplied even compile if you were to comment out the code inside the foreach, the Sitecore MultilistField stores it ids in a pipe separated string so your foreach would have to call GetItems() or at least split the raw value on a '|' to get a collection to iterate over?

However another way/use of the Sitecore ID TryParse method:

```
var subsidiariesIdList = new List<ID>();

    MultilistField multilistField = newsItem.Fields["Recipient Subsidiaries"];
    foreach (var item in multilistField)
{
ID id;
if (Sitecore.Data.ID.Parse(item.ToString(), out id))
{
    subsidiariesIdList.Add(id);
}
```

Or you could do:

```
MultilistField multilistField = newsItem.Fields["Recipient Subsidiaries"];

if (multilistField != null && multilistField.Count > 0)
{
var subsidiariesIdList = multilistField.GetItems().Select(i=>i.ID).ToList<ID>();
}
```

Enjoy.

P.s. Apologies for the poor formatting, I'm on an iPhone.